# File download - check for error before file write

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, networking

I'm using Qt to download a file from HTTP, for that, I'm using two signals:

```
connect(currentDownload, SIGNAL(finished()),
        SLOT(downloadFinished()));
connect(currentDownload, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
        SLOT(downloadReadyRead()));
```

Callbacks:

```
void DownloadManager::downloadFinished()
{
    output.close();

    if (currentDownload->error()) {
        // download failed
        std::cout << "Failed: [" << currentDownload->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt()
                     << "] " << qPrintable(currentDownload->errorString()) << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Download succeeded" << std::endl;
    }

    currentDownload->deleteLater();
    startNextDownload();
}

void DownloadManager::downloadReadyRead()
{
    output.write(currentDownload->readAll());
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I cant figure out how to skip writing the output file, if any error has occured during download for whatever reason. This is not logical - since I can only check for error during the `finished()` signal emitting. Checking for errors during the `readyRead()` signal won't show any, even though they exist. In the results, 404 output file will be written to the disk. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [QNetworkRequest](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkrequest.html) to get all the infromation.
Refer to this [example](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_Downloading_Files_QNetworkAccessManager_QNetworkRequest.php).

[QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) provide more signals to tackle errors.

```
QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(slotReadyRead()));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
        this, SLOT(slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),
        this, SLOT(slotSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));
```

Comment: So basically, I could skip the `readyRead()` signal and simply write the output in the `finished()` signal phase?

Comment: @Lucas i have updated the answer, QNetworkReply contains the informations about status. You should read on readyread, otherwise for big files it will be a problem to read at once. Along with that use can use error signal. Please mark as solved if it solves your problem.